# CRM 2011 Reports error

Tags: reporting-services, crm

I am working with CRM 2011 and I have some problems with a couple of reports created with SSRS. All the reports are working fine in CRM, but there are two reports that fails when I change any parameter. Here is the situation:

- When I open the reports they showed all the parameters and load its data.
- When I change any parameter value the report immediately fails and shows an error.
- The report works fine in SSRS and in another server.
- The report doesn't work in others CRM orgs in the same server.

I created a SQL trace thinking it was a data problem, but the trace didn't catch anything.
I activated CRM trace and catch an error, but I couldn't find any solution on the internet.
Please see the CRM trace attached in the end. I appreciate any help you can give me! If you need more details let me know!

Thanks in advance!

```
# CRM Tracing Version 2.0
# LocalTime: 2014-09-04 16:02:52.323
# Categories: 
# CallStackOn: No
# ComputerName: QAENACTWEB1
# CRMVersion: 5.0.9690.3911
# DeploymentType: OnPremise
# ScaleGroup: 
# ServerRole: AppServer, AsyncService, DiscoveryService, ApiServer, HelpServer, DeploymentService, SandboxServer, DeploymentManagementTools

[2014-09-04 16:02:52.323] Process: w3wp |Organization:9449861a-bf05-e311-a72c-005056b06ca2 |Thread:    4 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ErrorInformation.LogError  ilOffset = 0x17
>MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Error Message: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Error Details: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: https://qaenactweb1.wintrust.wtfc/EnActQA/CRMReports/rsviewer/QuirksReportViewer.aspx

Stack Trace Info: [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()

[HttpException: The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


[2014-09-04 16:02:52.354] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:    4 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x57
>UNEXPECTED: no fault?
[2014-09-04 16:02:52.354] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:    4 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #96492EFF: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
[2014-09-04 16:02:52.354] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:    4 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x69
>UNEXPECTED: no fault?
[2014-09-04 16:02:52.354] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:    4 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.Web.HttpException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #F7618FAB: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[2014-09-04 16:02:52.354] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:    4 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x69
>UNEXPECTED: no fault?
[2014-09-04 16:02:52.354] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:    4 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 1893b8fe-e996-41d7-84b3-ae4db3007082 | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #8EA3A629: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:9449861a-bf05-e311-a72c-005056b06ca2 |Thread:   75 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ErrorInformation.LogError  ilOffset = 0x17
>MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Error Message: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Error Details: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: https://qaenactweb1.wintrust.wtfc/EnActQA/CRMReports/rsviewer/QuirksReportViewer.aspx

Stack Trace Info: [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.]
   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()

[HttpException: The URL-encoded form data is not valid.]
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

[HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.]
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)


[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   75 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x57
>UNEXPECTED: no fault?
[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   75 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #C5E939C1: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   75 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x69
>UNEXPECTED: no fault?
[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   75 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.Web.HttpException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #553C429E: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The URL-encoded form data is not valid. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   75 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ExceptionConverter.ConvertToFault  ilOffset = 0x69
>UNEXPECTED: no fault?
[2014-09-04 16:10:53.183] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   75 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 8404d5fd-0269-4bf7-a459-8b6b02fe868b | ExceptionConverter.ConvertMessageAndErrorCode  ilOffset = 0x23B
>System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #00192A8D: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
>   at System.Web.HttpValueCollection.FillFromEncodedBytes(Byte[] bytes, Encoding encoding)
>   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the size of the parameters I was using in the report.

To fix it I changed the aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys value in the webconfig.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661403